# combine string with column name in query with sha1

Tags: mysql, sql, sha1, concatenation

I would like to hash the passwords in my database with another column of the same table. I have been trying to do this with a query, but I keep getting the same error.

This is an example query I use for testing the login. 12345678 is the password and I want to use the email address as a hash.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
SHA1(CONCAT('12345678', `email`)) = password
```

When I execute this in mysql I get the following error:

```
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an explicit collation

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE SHA1(CONCAT('12345678', `email`)) = password collate utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: This gives the error: 
#1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Comment: It did work after changing the character set of the table to utf8. Thanks!